# Writing an .add*() plug-in function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Okay, so I have discovered how to write jQuery plug-ins and I think this will tidy up my code a lot. I've been looking at a lot of tutorials which just adds style to the set of matched elements passed on the plug-in function.

...but I want to add new elements to the when using my function. Say that I want to do this:

```
$children
    .addCousins()
        .addClass("x")
    .end()
    .addClass("y");
```

So I've written this function, `.addCousins()`. What it does, nobody knows, but know that it works in theory. I only need to wrap my head around how to add more elements (if there are any) when `.addCousins()` is called. For each element in `$children` there can be zero or more "cousins", which should be added when doing the `.each()` in the plug-in function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        addCousins: function () {
            return this.each(
                    function () {
                        var index = $(this)
                            .prevAll("td.radio")
                                .andSelf()
                                    .length - 1;

                        $(this)
                            .prev("td[rowspan=2]")
                                .parent()
                                    .next()
                                        .children("td.radio")
                                            .eq(index); // here is the "cousin" which should be added to the selection
                    }
                );
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've been trying various solutions all day, but no progress yet. The selection of the cousin (the implementation of the selection you need not worry about) is done in the inner anonymous function, but, yeah, I don't really know how to go from here.

I hope I've been more or less clear about what I want.

**Edit #1.** Here is some testable HTML (I think)...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Here are cousins</td>
        <td class="radio">1</td>
        <td class="radio">2</td>
        <td class="radio">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="radio">4</td>
        <td class="radio">5</td>
        <td class="radio">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Here are NO cousins</td>
        <td class="radio">7</td>
        <td class="radio">8</td>
        <td class="radio">9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...and my updated plug-in function.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        cousins: function () {
            this
                .each(
                    function () {
                        var index = $(this)
                            .prevAll("td.radio")
                                .andSelf()
                                    .length - 1;

                        $(this)
                            .prev("td[rowspan=2]")
                                .parent()
                                    .next()
                                        .children("td.radio")
                                            .eq(index)
                                                .addClass("cousin");
                                            .end()
                                        .end()
                                    .end()
                                .end()
                            .end()
                            .prev()
                                .find("td[rowspan=2]")
                                    .nextAll("td.radio")
                                        .eq(index)
                                            .addClass("cousin");
                    }
                );

            return $("td.cousin")
                .removeClass("cousin");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If table cell 2 is selected an passed on to `.cousins()`, table cell 4 should be returned. Vice versa for table cell 4...

**Edit #2.** My (not yet working) update:

```
cousins: function () {
    var $cousins = $();

    this
        .each(
            function () {
                var index =
                    $(this)
                        .prevAll("td.radio")
                            .andSelf()
                                .length - 1;
                var $next = null;
                var $prev = null;

                $next = 
                    $(this)
                        .prev("td[rowspan=2]")
                            .parent()
                                .next()
                                    .children("td.radio")
                                        .get(index);
                $prev =
                    $(this)
                        .parent()
                            .prev()
                                .find("td[rowspan=2]")
                                    .nextAll("td.radio")
                                        .get(index);

                if ($next == null && $prev == null) {
                    $cousins.push($(this));
                } else {
                    $cousins.push($next);
                    $cousins.push($prev);
                }
            }
        );

    return $cousins;
}
```

Comment: Could you define the rules which considers an element as "cousin"? (Adapted) from Wikipedia: `element which shares one or more common ancestors (other than a parent, child, ancestor, descendant, sibling, descendant/child of a sibling, or sibling of an ancestor/parent).`

Comment: A cousin here is a `<td>` cell just above or below the selected `<td>` (I have only implemented below here, I think). If it's wise to name them "cousins" I do not know, but it works for me, but pay no attention to my naming. :)

Comment: The naming seems appropriate, but maybe with some of the HTML it'd be slightly easier to visualize what you're trying to do. `=]`

Comment: The HTML is essentially `<tr><td rowspan="2"></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr>`. If you, for example, would select any `<td>` (not the `rowspan` one) I want to get it and its cousin (above or below). If you select both `<td>` in one row I want to get both cousins, but if there's no `rowspan` attribute there are no cousins.

Comment: Here's a demo (the first question has two rows): http://viktor.hembrink.se/4it/resus/grid2/ That one works, but its code is messy and I wanted to tidy up using the plug-in approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viktor, assuming your code to correctly select the elements of interest (cousins), then there's a number of ways to approach adding them to the original selection.

A consideration is that the elements in the returned jq object should be in DOM order and fortunately, "as of jQuery 1.4 the results from `.add()` will always be returned in document order (rather than a simple concatenation) `.add()`". pimvdb's code correctly addresses this.

On another tack, I would prefer the additional flexibility offerd by a `.cousins()` plugin rather than `.addCousins()`, where :

- `.cousins()` would select just the cousins
- `.cousins().andSelf()` would be equivalent to `.addCousins()`

Here's the code for `.cousins()` :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        cousins: function(options) {
            var settings = {
                sibling_selector: '*',
                uncle_selector: '*',
                cousin_selector: '*'
            };
            if (options) {
                $.extend(settings, options);
            }
            var c = [];//cousins
            this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var index = $this.parent().children(settings.sibling_selector).index($this);
                $this.parent().siblings(settings.uncle_selector).each(function() {
                    c.push($(this).children(settings.cousin_selector).get(index));
                });
            });
            return this.pushStack(c);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5YzKT/1/)**

Notes:

- to generalize the plugin, this version accepts an options map (see demo).
- `.pushStack()` allows the method chain `.cousins(...).andSelf()` and `.cousins(...).end()` to behave as expected.

Comment: Huh, that is a very interesting solution, which I never would have thought about, using classes as flags. Is that standard for plug-in selecting? Regarding your advice about using `.cousins()` instead of `.addCousins()`: how would I use this from my script? Let's say I do a `$(this).prevAll("td").andSelf().addCousins().nowDoSomethingWithChildrenAndCousins()` when `$(this)` is a clicked table cell. How would I rewrite this to use `.cousins()`, since I need to select the prior selected elements again? Also, I cannot notice any difference between your two code previews, but thanks!

Comment: Never mind on that last question, `.andSelf()` seems to do what I want, as you said.

Comment: I can't quite get it to work, but maybe there's a problem with my traversing. Hmmm...

Comment: @Viktor, I can't test without the appropriate HTML. Can you add to you original post please.

Comment: @Viktor, I have only just started to look at the actual "cousins" paradigm. Genealogically, "cousins" are parents' siblings' children but I can't make this definition tally with what you describe. Unless I have misread, the provisos in the paradigm make it very specific to your application. I'm starting to wonder if this problem really qualifies as a plugin, which, in any case, would only make sense if you needed to invoke the "cousins" paradigm on two or more root elements simultaneously. You can still have reusable code by creating a regular javascript function.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it is very specific to my application and may not really qualify as a plug-in, but the script code will be very neat if I write it as a plug-in and may simplify further development of this script, if needed. I have a lot of behaviours further on in the code which require this function (and I have a few other plug-in functions too). In fact, I've already tried having it as JS function and it worked, but as I am new to jQuery (and JS; about two weeks in) I thought it'd be fun to try writing a simple plug-in for my application.

Comment: By the way, what's your take on pimvdb's solution here? You talk about DOM order in your solution (which I really do not know much about). Does pimvdb's solution guarantee DOM order? It seems to work, and it doesn't do an extra select via `$(".cousin")` which I guess would be a bit slower?

Comment: Viktor, @pimvdb 's solution is pretty good. My concerns over reflecting DOM order were unfounded (since jQuery 1.4 the results from [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) will always be returned in document order) and I need to edit my answer. However I think I'm right in saying that pimvdb's solution doesn't address your "above or below the selected <td>" requirement, and will find cousins in the third "no cousins here" row. If I'm right then there's a way to go yet.

Comment: Okay, yes, I'm aware that the solution does not exactly fit the assignment, but I'm working on getting there. I think I want to do the `.cousins()` method rather than the `.addCousins()` if `.andSelf()` works as expected. I created an empty jQuery object, `var $cousins = $();` which I add to in the loop and then return. My (not yet working) function can be found as edit #2 in my original post, if you'd like to give me some feedback.

Comment: Viktor, I've made some progress too, with emphasis on controlling behaviour with options. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5YzKT/1/).

Comment: That is great! I will give you the correct answer and implement it first thing tomorrow. Having a class flags on the rows may be unavoidable, but maybe I can place them out when loading the page and not have it in the HTML. Well, thanks! Although I would like to give some recognition pimvdb also, but I don't have enough rep yet to vote.

Comment: Viktor, agreed @pimvdb deserves some rep. You can vote later when you've got enough rep. As far as I'm aware there's no time limit. You can bookmark the question in your browser or rediscover it under "activity" in your profile.

Comment: Everything's working now! Thanks a bunch, but I would like it if you could tell me how `this.pushStack()` removes the previous selection. I'm guessing that `this` still holds the children and then you push the cousins, but the children actually are deleted. This is the desired behaviour, but how? :)

Comment: Viktor, `this` at the outermost scope of a jQuery plugin is the jQuery object on which the plugin is currently being invoked. jQuery objects have an internal stack of selections, which changes every time the object's selection is changed, and is the storage mechanism that allows `.end()` and `.andSelf()` to work. ...

Comment: ... Methods such as`.find()`, `.eq()`, `.parent()` and `closest()` cause a new selection to be pushed onto the stack by calling `.pushstack()` internally. `.pushStack()` is also available to be called externally as a general purpose method for  changing a jQuery object's selection and updating the stack in the same way as happens with those other methods.

Comment: I see, thank you. One last question: is there any particular reason we're creating a default JS array and pushing elements to it? What if we had `var $c = $()`?

Comment: A simple JS array is used for efficiency. A jQuery object could indeed be used but would be wasteful of both processing power and memory. Ultimately the `.pushStack()` method will discard whichever argument is passed to it (c or $c) - the method updates the original jQuery object (as is the object of the exercise).

Comment: Great, it's little things like that are hard to figure out when starting out. You've been a tremendous help and I cannot thank you enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to add elements to the set, and have `.end` get you back the previous set.

You can use `.add` for this: http://jsfiddle.net/AjkRb/1/.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        addCousins: function () {
            var toAdd = [];
            this.each(function () {
                var index = $(this)
                    .prevAll("td.radio")
                    .andSelf()
                    .length - 1;

                toAdd.push($(this)
                    .parent()
                    .next()
                    .children("td.radio")
                    .get(index));  // add native element (get instead of eq)
            });
            return this.add(toAdd);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Usage can then be as follows:

```
$("tr:first td.radio")
  .addCousins()
    .addClass("red")
    .end()
  .addClass("big");
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought along those lines before, but as I'm not experienced in JS it came out wrong.

Comment: What if I follow Beetroot-Beetroot's advice and do a `.cousins()` function instead where I do not want to return the original elements? `return toAdd;` doesn't quite work.